# how we can go to page 1 and 2 and 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a mobile web application using JavaScript (PhoneGap), the problem as following:

I have 3 page javascript that will dynamically create the html contained in the page,
  The first page contains butoon 1

The second page contains butoon 2

The third page contains butoon 3

we cliqunt on butoon one we go to the second page, click on the button 2 on the third page passes.

all goes well at the beginning, but if I return to page 1 and I would have go to the second page, the program directly  shows page 1 ,without going through the two previous.

i think beacause, I should delete the previous event, or cache  what you say?

Page 1

```
$('#header-left-container').prepend(results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail +"" +
                "<br>" +
                "<img src='../js/images/add.png' name="+results.rows.item(i).IdTypeTravail+" >" +
                "<textarea rows='6'  cols='60' id='"+results.rows.item(i).IdTypeTravail+"'   name='"+results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail+"'> </textarea><br><br>" );


 $('img').live('tap',function(e)
         {

     //-------------Pass param with localstorage

         window.localStorage.setItem("id_grp", id_grp_tr);
         window.localStorage.setItem("id_travail", e.target.name);

            $.mobile.changePage('../prestation_html/list_rubrique.html' , {role: 'dialog', transition: 'flip'});
         }
         );
```

Page 2

```
$('#lbtn').append('<input type="button" value="Consulter" onclick="go()"  id="Consulter">');

function go()
    {

        if(s == 0)
            {
            var sel_id_rub = $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id');//ID of Rubrique

             window.localStorage.setItem("id_rub", sel_id_rub);       //Id Rubrique
        //alert(sel_id_rub);

             liste_Phrase();

            }
```

Page 3

```
    $('#lbtn').append('<input type="button" value="Ajouter"  id="ajouter">');

$('#ajouter').live('click',function(e)
         {
        // alert( $("label[for='" + ( $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id') ) + "']").text() );
     window.localStorage.setItem("phrase", $("label[for='" + ( $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id') ) + "']").text());       //Id Rubrique

     $.mobile.changePage('../prestation_html/etape'+window.localStorage.getItem("id_grp")+'.html');
         }
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to use plugin that make use of HTML5 History/State in modern browser as:

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/